# TURN server installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows, stun, turn

How to install TURN server on Windows 7 . 
I've found many resource there: http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/

But not for windows ...
If any idea please response.

Comment: I've compiled [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) for Windows using Cygwin.  That's the only reliable way to run code developed for Linux to compile and run on Windows.

Comment: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

See [Pion TURN](https://github.com/pion/turn), it is written in pure Go and therefore runs even on Windows XP. The download is a single executable in the releases section.